# Accessing UIBarButtonItem textfield.text using swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uibarbuttonitem

I have a textfield in a toolbar on the bottom of my view that will be used for posting comments.

```
@IBOutlet var commentText: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBAction func commentButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    println(commentText.text) // dosent work
}
```

I am trying to get the textfield.text but I can't just say commentText.text because it is a UIBarButtonItem. I tried commentText.target!.text but that didn't work. I just started using swift 2 weeks ago so I am using the story board to put in items rather than programmatically making them

Comment: Where is you UITextfield  I can just see a UIBarButtonItem?

Comment: In my storyboard, I have a tableviewController that has a toolbar on the bottom. I dragged a textfield into the toolbar, and then when I made the outlet it says its a UIBarButtonItem, instead of uitextfield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UITextField is the UIBarButtonItem's `customView`. But even then the `customView` will just be a UIView, so you must cast it down to tell the compiler it is a UITextField.

So:

```
println((commentText.customView as! UITextField).text)
```

Comment: You're very welcome. This is the trouble with doing things in Interface Builder (the storyboard editor): it disguises what you are _really_ doing (from a code point of view). It is not easy to know about the `customView` from within Interface Builder!